# JavaScript regex match characters inside quotes and not in character set

Tags: javascript, regex, quotes

I have a string I would like to split using `#, ., [], or {}` characters, as in CSS. The desired functionality is:
- Input:
`"div#foo[bar='value'].baz{text}"`
- Output:
`["div", "#foo", "[bar='value'", ".baz", "{text"]`

This is easy enough, with this RegEx:
`input.match(/([#.\[{]|^.*?)[^#.\[{\]}]*/g)`
However, this doesn't ignore syntax characters inside quotes, as I would like it too. (e.x. `"div[bar='value.baz']"` should ignore the `.`)

How can I make the second part of my RegEx (the `[^#.\[{\]}]*` portion) capture not only the negated character set, but also any character within quotes. In other words, how can I implement the RegEx, `(\"|').+?\1` into my current one.

**Edit:**
I've figured out a regex that works decent, but can't handle escaped-quotes inside quotes (for example: `"stuff here \\" quote "`). If someone knows how to do that, it would be extremely helpful:

`str.match(/([#.\[{]|^.*?)((['"]).*?\3|[^.#\[\]{\}])*/g);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "div#foo[bar='value.baz'].baz{text}";
str.match(/(^|[\.#[\]{}])(([^'\.#[\]{}]+)('[^']*')?)+/g)
// [ 'div', '#foo', '[bar=\'value.baz\'', '.baz', '{text' ]
```

Comment: I modified it slightly to handle quotes inside `{}` and multiple `bar=value`'s inside `[]`: `str.match(/(^|[\.#[\]{}])(([^'\.#[\]{}]+)('[^']*')?|('[^']*'))+/g)`

Answer (score 2):

```
var tokens = myCssString.match(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|"(?:[^"\\]|\\[\s\S]*)"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\[\s\S])*'|[\{\}:;\(\)\[\]./#]|\s+|[^\s\{\}:;\(\)\[\]./'"#]+/g);
```

Given your string, it produces

```
div
#
foo
[
bar=
'value.foo'
]
.
baz
{
text
}
```

The RegExp above is loosely based on the [CSS 2.1 lexical grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, and i can't stress this enough: you shouldn't use regexps to parse css, you should use a real parser, for instance http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/ or similar - many have built them, no need for you to reinvent the wheel.

that said, to solve your current problem do this:

```
var str = "div#foo[bar='value.foo'].baz{text}";

str.match(/([#.\[{]|^.*?)(?:[^#\[{\]}]*|\.*)/g);

//["div", "#foo", "[bar='value.foo'", ".baz", "{text"]
```

Comment: The input string isn't literal CSS, actually. I'm trying to write a regex that can split up the input string by the characters listed above. I want to include `.` in the split, but ignore it (or any of the characters listed above) if they are inside quotes.